# How to get the string (of source-code) that generated a lambda-expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, tostring

(for LISP hackers in short: I'm looking for the LISP-quote equivalent in C#)

I'm trying to write a meaningful ToString-method for a class which has a Func as member. Experiened API-users can set this member via setter-method like

```
myClassObject.SetFunction( (x) => x*x );
```

Now, when I use the ToString-method on the member it only returns

```
System.Func<double,double>
```

which is not very helpful. What would be helpful is

```
"(x) => x*X"
```

Is there any (preferable easy) way to do that?

Thanks for any help or comments.

*Edit: corrected some typos*

Comment: What if a user calls the method like `SetFunction(MyFunc)`? What about `Func<double,double> myFunc = x => x*x; SetFunction(myFunc);`? Unless you store an `Expression<Func<double,double>>`, this seems like it would be difficult or impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Expression<Func<double,double>> expr = x => x * x;
string s = expr.ToString(); // "x => (x * x)"
```

Comment: This looks very neat. Is there a way to generate the expression from a given lambda or would I have to update my API such that it takes Expressions as arguments?

Comment: Hm. In general, this solution looks pretty good and I'm considering to update the API since it would only break where users have originally provided delegates or function pointers.

However, I have a new problem: if the user captures a variable state in the function, it still prints something ugly:

    int testInt = 10;
    Expression<Fun<double,double>> expr = x => x * testInt;
    string s = expr.ToString(); // "x => x * [UGLY CODE].testInt

Is there a way around that as well? That would be the cherry on top.

Comment: @Michael If a variable has been captured, then it's really being promoted to a field on a compiler-generated class. In order to ensure that its name doesn't clash, the compiler gives it a *very* funky name. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Alright then. I can produce a work-around for most usage cases and in the hopefully few corner cases, the support guys that have to get enlighted from the logs will probably have to reach API-user anyway.

Thanks all!

Comment: Hint: The `Expression<TDelegate>` class is from the System.Linq.Expressions namespace.

Answer (score 1):

None that I know of since that string has never entered the system, only IL was somehow generated and stored with a reference... you would need to "decompile" the IL to some meaningful string...

With [`CodeExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeexpression.aspx) there is possibility to call [`GenerateCodeFromExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.icodegenerator.generatecodefromexpression.aspx) via an instance of [`CodeDomProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx) which has built-in implementations for C# / VB / JScript... but I would be surprised if that met your needs...

Another option: With [`Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) you could use [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.tostring.aspx)  - this works with [`LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) too since that is just a descendant.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to store your delegate as an expression, you can achieve what you want. The code would look something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<double, double>> myFunc;
private Func<double, double> cachedDelegate; 

public void SetFunc(Expression<Func<double,double>> newFunc)
{
    this.myFunc = newFunc;
    this.cachedDelegate = null;
}

public double ExecFunc(double x)
{
    if (this.myFunc != null)
    {
        if (this.cachedDelegate != null)
        {
            return this.cachedDelegate(x);
        }
        else
        {
            this.cachedDelegate = this.myFunc.Compile();
            return this.cachedDelegate(x);
        }
    }

    return 0.0;
}

public string GetFuncText()
{
    if (this.myFunc != null)
    {
        return this.myFunc.ToString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

In order to actually use the lambda expression, you have to compile it first. Storing it in a delegate means you only take that hit once.

Also, this approach means that users have to use a lambda, since method groups aren't convertible to `Expression<Func<>>`. That's not a huge concern, though, since instead of passing `MyMethod`, a user could pass `x => MyMethod(x)`.

The calling code would look something like this:

```
myObject.SetFunc(x => 2*x);
Console.WriteLine(myObject.GetFuncText());
```

One final note is that the above sample is not thread-safe, so if you expect to have the methods called from multiple threads, some sort of synchronization would be appropriate.